# django "exclusive" checkbox

Tags: django, django-admin

I was wondering about how could I have in Django an "exclusive" Checkbox and set it in the admin? What I mean is that I have an app that stores polls and there can only be one in the frontpage, so I add a front_page field to the DB and make it bool. True show, False don't. So whenever I set in the admin a poll's front_page field to true I want every other poll to be set to false, this editing being done in the admin. As a Flasker I can think of 100 ways of doing it elsewhere, but this django thing has got me confused. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you want to do is override the save method of the model that has the exclusive flag, and then in the save method check to see if the flag is turned on.  If it is, then do a query to find all the records that have the flag turned on and turn them off.  Then save. It would look something like this:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    #...
    front_page = models.BooleanField()
    #...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.front_page:
            Poll.objects.filter(front_page=True).update(front_page=False)

        super(Poll, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Hope this helps!